# Javascript - Count number of consecutive character occurrences

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have been trying to solve this problem for some time now and I have partially managed to achieve it.

I am trying to write a function that will return a nested array, each array element will contain the number of consecutive chars found in a given string.

For example: for the given string "aaaabccaadeeee", the function should return nested array
[[4, a] [1, b] [2, c] [2, a] [1, d][4, e]]

I have managed to write the following function but it returns
[ [ 4, 'b' ], [ 0, 'c' ], [ 1, 'a' ], [ 1, 'd' ], [ 0, 'e' ] ]

What am I doing wrong?

```
function consecutiveArray(str) {

  const chunks = str.split("");
  let counter = 0;
  const finalArray = [];
  let  prevItem;


  for(chunk of chunks){

    if(!prevItem || prevItem === chunk){
      counter++
    } else {
      finalArray.push([counter, chunk])
      counter=0;
    }

    
    prevItem = chunk;
  }

  

  return finalArray;
  
}


console.log(consecutiveArray('aaaabccaadeeee'))
```

Comment: why dont you debug it. Use console log statemenets and see what is heppening in the loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `else` clause is wrong, you should push the counter for `prevItem` and initialize the count to `1`. Also, push the final counter the after the loop.

```js
function consecutiveArray(str) {
  const chunks = str.split("");
  let counter = 0;
  const finalArray = [];
  let  prevItem;
  for(chunk of chunks){
    if(!prevItem || prevItem === chunk){
      counter++
    } else {
      finalArray.push([counter, prevItem])
      counter=1;
    }
    prevItem = chunk;
  }
  finalArray.push([counter, prevItem])
  return finalArray;
}
console.log(consecutiveArray('aaaabccaadeeee'))
```

Comment: could you please explain, how does this ```prevItem``` is getting value for the next element?

Comment: In the `else` clause, you were pushing `[counter, chunk]`, now the else clause will get executed when `prevItem !== chunk`, right so basically now `chunk` is a new character and `counter` holds the count for `prevItem`, that's why I pushed `[counter, prevItem]`. Also, since `chunk` is the first occurrence of a new character, hence I set the counter to 1. Finally, after the loop, the counter for the last character will not pushed, that's why another push statement, after the loop.

Comment: @Nikkkshit explained above.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`String.matchAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll) to match all the groups of characters in your string; then just iterate the matches to produce your desired result:

```js
const str = 'aaaabccaadeeee'

const res = Array.from(str.matchAll(/(.)\1*/g)).map(([m, g]) => [m.length, g])

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way of doing it without RegExp:

```js
const str="aaaabccaadeeee";

const res=[];
str.split("").reduce((a,c,i)=>{
 if(a!==c) res.push([0,c]);
 ++res.at(-1)[0];
 return c;
},null);
console.log(res);
// for comparison: Nick's solution:
console.log([...str.matchAll(/(.)\1*/g)].map(([m,g])=>[m.length,g]))
```